# No route matches error but rake routes finds it, Rails.application.routes recognises it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Strangely when I include "resources :blogs" to my routes.rb I get the following error for any other path I try to reach:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blogs"}
```

The only path I don't get this error for is the "/blogs/:id(.:format)" itself.

Rake routes (**"show" for "blogs" in line 5**):

```
    blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)          blogs#index
          POST   /blogs(.:format)          blogs#create
 new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)      blogs#new
edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format) blogs#edit
     blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)      blogs#show
          PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)      blogs#update
          DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)      blogs#destroy
  root           /                         pages#home
     home        /home(.:format)           pages#home
 products        /products(.:format)       pages#products
 services        /services(.:format)       pages#services
 research        /research(.:format)       pages#research
                 /blog(.:format)           pages#blog
  contact        /contact(.:format)        pages#contact
```

On the other hand when tried in console there is no such error for "/products" (for instance) which **in the browser** returns the "No route matches" error:

```
1.9.3p327 :010 > Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/products"
=> {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"products"} 
1.9.3p327 :011 > Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/blogs/1"
=> {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blogs", :id=>"1"}
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my blogs_controller.rb:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

and my show.html.erb of the blogs:

```
<%= @blog.title %>, <%= @blog.description %>
```

So far this is all I have developed to test my Blog model.

Comment: Can you post the url you're requesting in your browser, and the lines preceding the error message ?

Comment: Sure. The error message is just that one line that I have included in the question. It's "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blogs"}". The URL that I'm requesting is "localhost:3000". I get the exact same error message for "localhost:3000/products", "localhost:3000/services", and so on. Basically for all paths of the "pages" Controller.

Comment: One more thing that might help resolve this problem: All paths included in my routes.rb were reachable just before I added the "resources :blogs". It all started to act weirdly after I included that one line.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have something like

```
<%= link_to "Blogs", blog_path =>
```

in layout template. If so, correct it  to `<%= link_to "Blogs", blogs_path =>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dimuch. Unfortunately, that's not the case. I have updated the question with regards to your reply. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks :)